# How to find records from one table where multiple columns meet different criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that takes `@n int` as a parameter. The procedure is basically trying to find a subset of records from one table that need to have some information re-calculated, based on the records' dates being older than some dates in another table.

The procedure must do the following:

- Find records from `Table1` where `Table1.UpdatedOn` is within the past `@n` days.
- Find records from `Table2` where `Table2.EndDate` is **before** the date in the record(s) returned by the first bullet point (so basically if `T2.EndDate` < `T1SubSet.UpdatedOn`, then we want that record)
- If `Table2.EndDate` is `null`, then we use a different date column for this comparison.
- Insert those records from `Table2` that meet this criteria into `Table3`. More specifically, it should insert `Table2.RecordID` into `Table3`, as well as some "hard coded" values.

This is what I've got:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)
SELECT RecordID, GETDATE(), 0, null 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT RecordID FROM Table2 WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL AND EndDate < (SELECT UpdatedOn FROM Table1 WHERE UpdatedOn > DATEADD(day, @n, GETDATE())) OR
     SELECT RecordID FROM Table2 WHERE EndDate IS NULL And SomeOtherDate < (SELECT UpdatedOn FROM Table1 WHERE UpdatedOn > DATEADD(day, @n, GETDATE())))
```

Logically, this probably isn't right but either way when I try to execute that command I get two errors:

> Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my nested queries.

Comment: Match ('s and )'s.

Comment: The problem comes after the OR.

Comment: for your date that is not used if it is null, then your search parameter can be COALESCE(EndDate , SomeOtherDate )

Comment: we can still do more if it isn't right yet, you've got 'Find records from Table1 where Table1.UpdatedOn is within the past @n days.' that's ok, but in the second point ' before the date in the record(s) returned by the first bullet point' does bullet point 1 give multiple dates?  Which date do we use if it does, so the records pair together, or will we take some minimum of the set - if you ask another question, try and give an example with just a few records, even just two records in the first set you return, then explain how the dates work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TOP 1` and `OR`

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)
SELECT RecordID, GETDATE(), 0, null 
FROM Table2
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT RecordID FROM Table2 
        WHERE 
            (
                EndDate IS NOT NULL AND 
                EndDate < (SELECT TOP 1 UpdatedOn FROM Table1 WHERE UpdatedOn > DATEADD(day, @n, GETDATE()))
            ) OR
            (
                EndDate IS NULL And 
                SomeOtherDate < (SELECT TOP 1 UpdatedOn FROM Table1 WHERE UpdatedOn > DATEADD(day, @n, GETDATE()))
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't blow up, though I need to fix the logic before it gets the records I'm after. Accepting as the answer as it solves the question of "What's syntactically wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

Use COALESCE for this. It gets the first parameter in a list that is not null. It is ISO standard and very useful

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)
SELECT RecordID, GETDATE(), 0, null 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT RecordID FROM Table2 WHERE 
                COALESCE(EndDate, SomeOtherDate) 
                < (SELECT UpdatedOn FROM Table1 
                                    WHERE UpdatedOn > DATEADD(day, @n, GETDATE()))
```